# Create exception routine if module not found Python

Tags: python, exception, attributeerror, try-except

I have a simple Python programm. This programm contains two functions, that can be called by using programm.function_1() from a second programm. If a user types package.function_01() the attribute error 'module not found' comes up. I want to except that error and call the function help().

Where do I have to insert my try - except routine to handle the attribute error?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you at least provide an example? It will enable us to understand your question better.

Answer (score 0):

Surround the code that can break with a `try ... except` block. You may call your Exception handler under the `except SomeException:` clause

Take a look into Python exception docs [enter link description here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions)